# Something like "contains any" in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

The following (simplified) classes are mapped to the database via Hibernate:

```
class SystemUser {
    Set<UserGroup> groups;
}

class UserGroup {
    Set<Integer> permissions;
}
```

How can I select all SystemUsers with a certain permission, say permission `3`, with HQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select distinct u from SystemUser u join u.groups g 
where 3 in elements(g.permissions)
```